# g++ corrupting file and causing it to grow massively

Tags: c++, g++

EDIT: Oops! I meant to include my compile command. I used "g++ -g -o war war.h war.cpp"

EDIT 2: This is a Linux server I'm compiling using gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5). Also, I tried to reproduce the problem and was unable to, so I really have no idea what could have caused it now.

On a whim I decided to make a War (card game) simulator in c++. I was starting off the program and I wrote a header file with all my #includes and had the source code in another file. I accidentally had the #includes in both the header file and the source code and when I tried to compile, it started giving me all these errors saying (for example):

> war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\20' in program war.cpp:3815:12: warning:
>   null character(s) ignored war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\21' in program
>   war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\231' in program war.cpp:3815:18: warning:
>   null character(s) ignored war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\20' in program
>   war.cpp:3815:20: warning: null character(s) ignored war.cpp:3815:
>   error: stray '\20' in program war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\212' in
>   program war.cpp:3815: error: stray '\217' in program

Keep in mind, this program was <200 characters at this point, so something was causing the compiler to write all these characters to the file. I quickly figured out what the problem was and corrected it, but my question is, how did this happen? What caused the compiler to write to the program so massively? By the time I canceled the compiler (it looked like it was going to just keep going), the file had grown from a couple of hundred bytes to nearly 13 MB in just a few seconds. I'm no expert but it seems like this kind of thing could have security implications, especially since I was running this program over ssh on my university's CS department server.

For what it's worth, here's the code I had when I compiled:

war.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< pair<int, suit> > deck1;
    vector< pair<int, suit> >::iterator it1;

}
```

war.h:

```
#ifndef WAR_H
#define WAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum suit { HEARTS, SPADES, CLUBS, DIAMONDS };


#endif
```

Comment: Is this problem reproducible with the same input?  If it's not, then it sounds like your department server might have some bad RAM cells.

Comment: I haven' tried to reproduce the issue, but g++ only writes to its output files. So I guess maybe you specified `-o war.cpp`, or something of the sort? I'm not sure whether and why g++ would continue reading the source file after it has started writing the output, though.

Comment: Did the code above actually create the problem or has it since been modified?

Comment: Re what @SteveJessop said:  what was your compile command?

Comment: I compiled with "g++ -g -o war war.h war.cpp"

Comment: @user1454369: That totally was not your command, at least not unless the "server's hardware is broken" theory is correct. I've just mostly reproduced your symptoms with `g++ -g -o war.cpp war.h war.cpp` (I get the nul characters, but not the other stray unprintable characters, and I get a huge war.cpp file generated). Check the command history of your shell account on that server, I bet you find `-o war.cpp`!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a broken include guard.  e.g. this will do it to you.  I'm pretty sure you don't need two broken include guards for this to happen, but if you understand why this situation will cause you trouble you'll get the idea.

bar.h:

```
#define BAR__H  //whoops
#ifndef BAR_H

#include "foo.h"
int bar();

#endif
```

foo.h:

```
#define FOO__H  //whoops
#ifndef FOO_H

#include "bar.h"
int foo();

#endif
```

Comment: Could you explain that in greater detail. I do not see the connection.

Comment: @Sqeaky Edited post to include example.

Comment: Doesn't reproduce for me, instead I get an error `recurse1.h:4:22: error: #include nested too deeply` (I renamed your files, hence `recurse1.h` rather than `foo.h`). This is `g++ (GCC) 4.5.3`. No sign of the errors the questioner saw, and no 13MB files created.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. I would expect that include guard issues would either cause redefinition or undefined reference errors.

Comment: OP isn't including anything other than C and C++ headers.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because your file has some "misterious" symbols somewhere in the middle. Try find them with hex editor, for example. Try deleting this files and write them once again. Or paste this code somewhere, where you can see this symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the compiler(any compiler) should only reading the source and should never write back to it.

I would question the integrity of the disks on the server. If it just has a single disk it could be failing, I have seen RAIDs do odd things occasionally.

Another possibility is that the encoding is changing or being interpreted incorrectly. If the computer you wrote it on is windows based, it could be in a windows friendly encoding ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 ) where the compiler is likely expecting UTF8 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8 ). If this is the case you could switch to a text editor that lets you manually chose the character encoding.

If it is an encoding issue you can do as spo1ler said and remove extra non-rendering characters from the file with a hex editor. I had problems with a copyright symbol like this once.